# How can get the Transaction ID or Status for payment on Website?

Tags: paypal

I'm using PHP and this's my fist post and I have some doubts... The target is: "integrate the paypal payment for a online store, so when the user complete the car's items, he will be able to pay using PAYPAL platform, the website should receive some confirmation to ensure the purchase".

In my code I put the button for payment using this tutorial Client-Side REST (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/), I tried the button using the "test credentials" generated in SANDBOX/ACCOUNTS (buyer account test), but when the buy process finish I only receive de "alert()" message, but it's all :(....

I know !... I can change this alert() function for my own code, but the problem is: "where is the Confirmation ID o Transaction ID" for the payment ?

Whats I need to do to know where is the "Transaction ID" for the payment ?

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

Using the demo code, once you get the alert that the payment was successful you'll need to login to the sandbox account at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com. You'll see your payment processed with the transaction id. Typically you'll be able to gather the information from the API Response or using GET to retrieve the data.

Show payment details: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_get